# Sitecore SXA Dynamic Placeholders

Tags: sxa, scriban

We are trying to render dynamic placeholders with Scriban as follows:

`{{ sc_placeholder "relatedcontainer*" }}`

On our UAT instance the placeholder expands the wildcard out properly:  `relatedcontainer-1-1`.  However on our development machines it is rendering as `relatedcontainer*`

Both instances are using Sitecore 9.3.  Is there a setting that needs to be set to expand the wildcard field?  Any other ideas?

One more piece of information, we set `IsRenderingsWithDynamicPlaceholders` to true on the controller rendering

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore provided and we installed SC Hotfix 394455-1 SXA 9.3.0.2589.zip and this has resolved the issue.  If you have this same issue, please open a ticket with Sitecore to get this hotfix.